# Delay when updating form values with Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I've noticed that when I try to update a couple values in my `FormBuilder` right before submitting it with HTTPclient my values aren't updated. When I run the submit a 2nd time these values are updated.

```
private mergeDates(dateValue: string, timeValue: string): string {
  const returnValue = dateValue.toString().replace(' 00:00', ` ${timeValue}`);
  return returnValue;
}

private submitVacancy() {
  if (this.vacancyForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  const fValue = this.vacancyForm.value;
  const fControls = this.vacancyForm.controls;
  fControls['beginDateTime'].setValue(
    this.mergeDates(fValue['beginDate'], fValue['beginTime']),
  );
  fControls['endDateTime'].setValue(
    this.mergeDates(fValue['beginDate'], fValue['endTime']),
  );
  alert(JSON.stringify(fValue));
  this.http.post(`${this.apiUri}/addvacancy`, JSON.stringify(fValue));
}
```

Comment: HTML part please ?

Comment: what shows you the `JSON.stringify(fValue)` ?

Comment: You're assigning form value to `fValue` variable before calling `setValue` method on form controls. Try to move this assignment just above the line with `alert` function call.

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski I tried you suggestion and it worked like a charm.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following line to my code like Mateusz suggested and it now works fine.
My code now looks like this.

```
private mergeDates(dateValue: string, timeValue: string): string {
  const returnValue = dateValue.toString().replace(' 00:00', ` ${timeValue}`);
  return returnValue;
}
private submitVacancy() {
  if (this.vacancyForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  const fControls = this.vacancyForm.controls;
  let fValue = this.vacancyForm.value;

  fControls['beginDateTime'].setValue(
    this.mergeDates(fValue['beginDate'], fValue['beginTime']),
  );

  fControls['endDateTime'].setValue(
    this.mergeDates(fValue['beginDate'], fValue['endTime']),
  );

  fValue = this.vacancyForm.value;
  alert(JSON.stringify(fValue));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(fValue));
  this.http.post(`${this.apiUri}/vacancy`, JSON.stringify(fValue));
}
```

I added `fValue = this.vacancyForm.value;` right after I run my `setValue()`.